# Python Function To Return List

Tags: python

Python newbie here.I wrote this function to only return even numbers as a list but I am failing at doing this. Can you please help? This is my initial function which works fine but results are not coming out as a list:

```
def myfunc (*args):
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print (num)
```

When you call the function for example with the following arguments:

```
myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I am getting:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

but I need those to be in a list, what am I missing? This doesn't work either:

```
list = []
def myfunc (*args):
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print (list[num])
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: You are never adding the values to the list, e.g. `l.append(num)`. Note: don't use `list` as a variable name it hides python's `list` type.

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot that "list" was a reserved keyword as well as using the  append method to add to a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def myfunc (*args):
    mylist = []
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            mylist.append(num)
    return mylist
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Worked.

Comment: quick question, how did know that the return was supposed to line up with for and not if? Thank you!

Comment: It needs to line up with `for` since the `return` should happen only after the loop is completed. If it were lined up with `if` it would only make one pass though the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning anything. You may want to get the elements by

```
def myfunc (*args):
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            yield num
```

Or create a temporary list:

```
def myfunc (*args):
    lst = []
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            lst.append(num)
    return lst
```

You can check your returned value in REPL:

```
>> type(print(num)) # print() returns None
NoneType
```

---

Explanation: In short, `yield` returns an element per time the function is iterated - and only returns an element once. So the function is also called a "generator". There is [an excellent post about `yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do). I cannot explain better than it.

---

**Update:** Don't use `list` as variable name, `list` is a builtin method.

Comment: You may want to explain how `yield num` actually works. Remember, he/she is a newbie. (sorry for being annoying :P)

Comment: Note: `list` is not a reserved keyword or you wouldn't be able to hide it with a variable, it is a builtin.